# Error installing Gdata on Ubuntu for Odoo 8 (404 Not Found)

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, odoo, odoo-8

I'm trying to install Odoo 8 on Ubuntu 16.04 but i also seem to need to download and install Gdata module for that, according to a toturial found in this website: https://www.getopenerp.com/easy-odoo8-installation/

While typing this command line:

```
sudo wget http://gdata-python-client.googlecode.com/files/gdata-2.0.17.tar.gz
```

I keep getting this error message :

```
--2018-10-30 20:00:23--  http://gdata-python-client.googlecode.com                      /files/gdata-2.0.17.tar.gz
Resolving gdata-python-client.googlecode.com (gdata-python-   client.googlecode.com)... 64.233.166.82, 2a00:1450:400c:c06::52
Connecting to gdata-python-client.googlecode.com (gdata-python-      client.googlecode.com)|64.233.166.82|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
018-10-30 20:00:24 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Does anyone have any clue on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tutorial and Odoo8 both are obsolete. Current version is Odoo 12. Gdata url you are trying to access, no longer exists. However you can install gdata with Python pip.

```
    `pip install gdata` // requires Python 2.5+
```

Or to upgrade, use:

```
    `pip install -U gdata`
```

You need to skip rest of the instructions in STEP 8 of tutorial.

Comment: Thanks alot for answering my question! It just worked :)